# How do you earn "banked" Mana?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

After a couple of matches, I've noticed I had 78 mana in my bank. I haven't sold any items or banked any using the forge. Are there other ways to earn Mana?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's from the [wiki](http://dungeondefenders.wikia.com/wiki/Mana#How_To_Gain_Mana):

> - It is possible to bank mana during the building phase using the
>     forge. (Only after first wave.)
> - Items left on the ground at the start of a wave get turned into mana
>     and split between the players.
> - End of Level - At the successful completion of a level, you will
>     receive some mana back for your towers.
> - Upon leaving a level - Items on the ground are sold and split between
>     the players
> - Extra items can be sold for mana based on their quality.
> - Mana can be traded between heroes in the tavern by dropping it.
>
>   - Access the Hero menu and choose "Drop Mana".
>   - Mana has a maximum of 100,000 per Drop.

Comment: just to add, the mana purchasing thing is not on the pc version yet